# Center logo in html5 nav

Tags: css, html

So I'm trying to center a logo in my nav section in html5.

```
  <header>
    <div class="container1">
       <nav>
           <div class="logo">Logo</div>
       </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
```

​
http://jsfiddle.net/RbctB/

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's about `margin:0 auto`? BTW: Centering to what? (horizontal - vertical)?

Answer (score 2):

Remove your `float: left;` and add `margin: 0 auto;`

http://jsfiddle.net/RbctB/2/

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `float:left` and expect to be able to center it.

By far the easiest way to center an element horizontally is by having its container use `text-align:center` and the affected element uses `display:inline-block` (and optionally `text-align:left` to override the container's alignment of text)

Answer (score 0):

Add `margin:0 auto;` to `.logo` and remove the `float:left`.

Also you are not using the `nav` element correctly, as it should contain navigation which it currently does not.

Answer (score 0):

**First:**

Erase this lines:

```
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

at your **#container1** style.

**Second:**

At your **.logo** style, erase:

```
float: left;
```

And add:

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

Can I suggest you to erase all styles that you don't use for clarifying code?

Hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

As the guys said above, this is just another way of saying the same.

```
.logo {
    float: left; /*remove */
    margin: 0 auto; /*add */
}
```